# “Invalid Column Name” in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I get an error “Invalid Column Name” in Visual studio even when all the columns are present in the table in Sql Server. Table column Name is AttandanceId but it shows error of “Invalid Column Name” ie. AttandanceId1 which is not present there in Sql Server Table Under Attandance

```
public IActionResult EmployeeReport(int id)
{
    var viewModel = new AttandanceViewModel();
    var EmployeeList = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();

    viewModel.DropFirstName = new SelectList(EmployeeList, "EmployeeId", "FirstName");
    viewModel.AttList = _dbContext.Attandance.Where(i => i.EmpId == id).ToList();
    ViewBag.Id = id;
    var Count = viewModel.AttList.Count();

    ViewBag.Counts = Count;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Could you give us your structure of class `Employees` ?

Comment: @public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [Required]


        public int SN { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Required]

        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DeptId")]
        public int Departmen

Comment: Entity uses a mapping file that has to be updated if the name in the database changes.  the mapping file links the database names to the classes in c#.  The class by itself will not be enough to determine the issue.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with @dweng's comment. `has to be updated if the name in the database changes`. BTW, Could you hit the breakpoint to debug than give us more details of your issue? which number line code you are getting the error?

Comment: Can you provide the related code about you have done? Also, please provide the database table you designed, which let us to check what is wrong with you. By the way you can edit your question to add some sample code. No need to add code in comment.

Answer (score 0):

i think you made some changes in sql table and then try to update data model, which is not updated successfully e.g. As you mention AttandanceId and AttandanceId1 which shows conflict.

simply do

- 1: delete your table or complete model and clean your solution.
- 2: add table/model again and build your solution, every think will be
  fine